# How can i make that the console, with the output, will not disapear after the program ends in VS 2010 express C++

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

How can i make that the console, with the output, will not disapear after the program ends in VS 2010 express C++?

i write in c and not in c++, soo i need a function and include path to library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing Ctrl+F5 ("Build -> Start Without Debugging") will run the application and automatically wait for a keypress before closing the console. However, as the name says, you do not have a debugger attached then.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply poll for input. This performs a block so that the function only returns when the user gives more input - usually enter. If you're on Windows you can also use system("PAUSE").

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

- Run the program from command prompt
- Add a `getchar()` before you return from main.
- Add `system("pause")` before you return from main

Answer (score 1):

```
int waitforenter(void) {
    int ch;
    puts("press ENTER (maybe twice)");

    /* get rid of a (possibly) pre existing '\n' */
    do {
        ch = getchar();
    } while ((ch != EOF) && (ch != '\n'));

    /* and again */
    if (ch != EOF) do ch = getchar(); while ((ch != EOF) && (ch != '\n'));
    return ch;
}
```

And then call `waitforenter()` right before the end of your `main()` function.